# Writing a CSV file from matlab efficiently

Tags: performance, matlab, csv

I have 3 arrays that I want to write to a csv file:

dates_array - `T x 1` vector of matlab serial dates;

observations - `T x N` array of numerical data;

string_array - `N x 1` vector of strings

I want to put everything into a cell array in a panel format. I can do a for loop for that. But when T and N are very large this is very inefficient;

```
clear all
clc

% Generate Data

T = 1000;
N = 100;

dates_array = 737791:1:737791+T-1;
dates_array = dates_array';
observations = rand(T,N);
string_array = string(char(randi([33 126],N,10)));

% Put in panel format
count = 1;
for i = 1:N
for j=1:T

    out_for_csv{count,1} = {datestr(dates_array(j,1))};
    out_for_csv(count,2) = {observations(j,i)};
    out_for_csv(count,3) = {string_array(i,1)};
    count = count + 1;
end
end


Tab = cell2table(out_for_csv);
writetable(Tab,'myDataFile.csv')
```

There needs to be a better way of doing this instead of the loop. I did try a few things but always fail to put everything together on the `out_for_csv` matrix.

E.g. one efficient way of getting the three columns vectors is:

```
column1 = repmat(datestr(dates_array(j,1)),N,1);
column2 = observations(:);
column3 = repelem(string_array,T,1);
```

Now I just need to figure out how to put these three columns together.

Comment: And... what is the question...? Jumping ahead, I can very much relate to your general circumstance so I would suggest the followings: 1) if you can make your data purely numeric, use `csvwrite` (or the now recommended `writematrix`; 2) if you cannot, and your data is large (like N>1 mil), use [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html); 3) until later Matlab versions, do not interact with `table` unless your data set is very very small (N<1000).

Comment: In between, do not use cells unless you are forced to. You have columns of data. So put columns into `table()` directly.

Comment: This last comment makes the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to shrink the execution time on my computer from around 21 seconds to 1.5 seconds for a 14x speed improvement!  What really made things go fast is to build a large character matrix in memory, then write it out with a single `fprintf` command.

A couple of minor changes I made to the code are to seed the random number generator so that I would get consistent random numbers so I could compare the original code to my new code.  I also limited the random character strings to only be upper case letters since the original code would sometimes pick a comma and that would lead to an inconsistent number of columns when the output file was read into Excel.

One tricky thing is when you write out the character maxtrix using `fprintf`, you need to transpose it since the `fprintf` works down each column first.

Here is the code:

```
T = 1000;
N = 100;

dates_array = 737791 + (0:(T-1))';
dates_array = datestr(dates_array);
% Add a comma after the dates
dates_array = [dates_array, repmat(',', T, 1)];
% Replicate the dates N times
dates_array = repmat(dates_array, N, 1);

% Seed the randon number generator to get consistent values so comparisons between versions can be made
rng(0)
observations = rand(T, N);
% convert from a matrix to a column
observations = reshape(observations, T*N, 1);
% Convert from numbers to characters
observations = num2str(observations, 5);
% Add a comma after the observations
observations = [observations, repmat(',', T*N, 1)];

% Make the matrix of strings
string_array = char(randi([65 90], 1, N * 10));
% Replicate T times
string_array = repmat(string_array, T, 1);
% Turn matrix of 10-char strings into a vector of 10-char strings
string_array = reshape(string_array, N * T, 10);

% Join the date, observations, strings, and carriage return
out = [dates_array, observations, string_array, repmat(newline, T*N, 1)];

title_row = 'col1,col2,col3';
num_extra_commas = size(out, 2) - length(title_row) - 1;
title_row = [title_row, repmat(',', 1, num_extra_commas), newline];
out = [title_row; out];

fid = fopen('myDataFileb.csv', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s', out');
fclose(fid);
```